# Make/Let/Get + Verb -Ing?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, causatives

I have previously learnt *Have + Verb ing* is possible. I'd like to know if Ing is possible with other causative verbs.

Allow me to give examples:

> Her mom *lets* her **listening** to music at the moment.
>
> Her mom *makes* her **mowing** the lawn.
>
> She gets her assistant to **finding** a solution for her at the moment.

If this is not possible, how could I say that something is happening at the current present time?

Comment: 'Have someone doing something' is idiomatic, but it's not with 'Let', 'Make' or 'Get'. But "Let/Make/Have someone do something", "Get someone to do something", "Make/Have/Get something done by someone" --all these are idiomatic and meaningful.

Comment: It's not a matter of individual verbs alone. there are constructions like _have `NP` `Infinitive VP`_ that have their own specific syntax and semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to transform the OP's sentences into the present progressive tense, the so called *causative* verb must be in the progressive form: Subject + be + V+ing.

- Her mum **is letting** her listen to some music at the moment.
- Her mom **is making** her mow the lawn.
- She'**s getting** her assistant to look for (OR *find a*) the solution at this moment in time.

From *[Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-causative-verb-1689833)*

> **A causative verb, which can be in *any* tense**, is generally followed by an object and another verb form—often an **infinitive** or a **participle**—and are used to describe something that happens because of a person, place, or thing whose actions bring about change in another entity.